# Me gustaria usar WITH antes de la consulta pero me salta error

Tags: sql

Pues quiero utilizar WITH antes de la consulta pero me salta un error, adjunto la consulta de como he puesto el WITH y el error.

```
DECLARE @cod_centro VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @fec_annomes int

SET @cod_centro='MC'
SET @fec_annomes='201810'


WITH TH_Hospitalizacion AS

(
select @cod_centro, @fec_annomes, 225,count(* ),getdate()
from TH_Hospitalizacion t 
where t.cod_centro = @cod_centro and year(t.fec_alta)*100+month(t.fec_alta) = @fec_annomes
and xti_excluido ='n' and xti_tipoProceso='H'
AND EXISTS (SELECT COD_EPISODIO FROM TH_TomaFormulario A WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN TH_ValorIndicadorTomaFormulario_2 B WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.cod_TomaFormulario = B.cod_TomaFormulario 
AND B.COD_INDICADOR IN ('5913',
'10965',
'48128')
and des_ValorIndicador IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '10')
AND t.cod_Episodio=A.cod_Episodio
AND A.cod_centro=@cod_centro)

)
```

Este es el mensaje del error.

```
Sintaxis incorrecta junto a la palabra clave 'with'. Si esta instrucción es una expresión de tabla común, una cláusula xmlnamespaces o una cláusula de contexto de seguimiento de cambios, la instrucción anterior debe terminarse con punto y coma.
```

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo lo agradecería bastante.

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Podras aclarar que motor de base de datos estas usando. y porque hay with en el medio?

Comment: Revisa el subselect del EXISTS, pareciera que dentro del ON tienes un vínculo hacia una columna de la tabla con alias "T".

Comment: Si la consulta en un primer momento funciona el problema es que cuando quiero poner el WITH me salta el error, esto lo estoy desarrollando en sql server 2012

Comment: Cuál es tu intención de usar el WITH!? quieres hacer un CTE!?

Comment: Si así es, me gustaría hacer un CTE

Comment: Agrega un `;` antes del `WITH ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas hacer es un CTE, en la parte final te estaba haciendo falta la invocación al CTE generado.

```
WITH TH_Hospitalizacion_CTE AS
(
    SELECT @cod_centro AS 'Cod_Centro', 
        @fec_annomes AS 'Fecha', 
        225 AS '225',
        count(* ) AS 'Count',
        getdate() AS 'GetDate'
    FROM TH_Hospitalizacion t 
    WHERE t.cod_centro = @cod_centro 
        AND year(t.fec_alta)*100+month(t.fec_alta) = @fec_annomes
        AND xti_excluido ='n' and xti_tipoProceso='H'
        AND EXISTS (SELECT COD_EPISODIO 
            FROM TH_TomaFormulario A WITH (NOLOCK)
            INNER JOIN TH_ValorIndicadorTomaFormulario_2 B WITH (NOLOCK) 
                ON A.cod_TomaFormulario = B.cod_TomaFormulario 
                AND B.COD_INDICADOR IN ('5913', '10965', '48128')
                AND des_ValorIndicador IN ('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9', '10')
                AND A.cod_centro=@cod_centro
            WHERE t.cod_Episodio=A.cod_Episodio
            )
)
SELECT *
FROM TH_Hospitalizacion_CTE
```

Cabe destacar 2 cosas:

1. Evita llamar al mismo CTE con un nombre ya asignado dentro de tus tablas, es por ello que lo cambié a TH_Hospitalizacion_CTE.
2. En el **ON** no hagas filtrados que no tengan que ver con la relación de tablas por los **JOINS**, en ese caso lo que debes hacer es el uso del **WHERE**.

**EDICION**

Lo que está faltando es que les des un alias a los campos calculados. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la Ayuda, he ejecutado la consulta que me pasa pero ahora tengo otro error
No se especificó ningún nombre de columna para la columna 1 de 'TH_Hospitalizacion_CTE'.
No se especificó ningún nombre de columna para la columna 2 de 'TH_Hospitalizacion_CTE'.
No se especificó ningún nombre de columna para la columna 3 de 'TH_Hospitalizacion_CTE'.
 y yo lo que quiero es que me muestre solo lo siguiente  cod_centro, fec_annomes, 225,count(* ),getdate()

Comment: Lo que estaba faltando era agregarle un alias a los campos calculados, ya actualicé la respuesta para que puedas hacer uso de ella.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, lo he ejecutado y funciona correctamente muchas gracias por toda la ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

La sintaxis de TSQL, exije que, si hay sentencias en el script previas a `with`, la última de estas termine siempre con `;`. El error es que en tu script original no existe ese `;`.

Dado que es el único caso (que yo conozca) en que TSQL tiene esa regla, es una práctica común iniciar siempre el CTE con `;`.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso, se resolverá de cualquiera de estas dos formas:

```
SET @fec_annomes='201810'; --; añadido aquí


WITH TH_Hospitalizacion AS

(
select @cod_centro, @fec_annomes, 225,count(* ),getdate()
from TH_Hospitalizacion t 
... el resto de tu código
```

Pero también así (y es la preferida de muchos):

```
SET @fec_annomes='201810'


; WITH TH_Hospitalizacion AS --al añadirlo aquí, siempre se cumple la regla

(
select @cod_centro, @fec_annomes, 225,count(* ),getdate()
from TH_Hospitalizacion t
```